# batch-file: variables in for loops

Tags: batch-file

im quite new to cmd-scripts and i encountered a problem.
i want to iterate through all files in the current folder and all its subfolders having certain endings that are stored in the array `%list%`. so i started with:

```
@for /R %%d in (.) do @( 
    cd %%d
    @(for %%a in (%list%) do @( 
       for %%f in (*.%%a) do @echo %%d/%%f
    ))          

)
```

this works however it produces paths like C:\test\.\myfile.txt
so i want to get a substring of the dir. since this does not work on variables like %%d, i tried to store %%d in a seperate variable:

```
@for /R %%d in (.) do @( 
    cd %%d
    set dir=%%d
    @(for %%a in (%list%) do @( 
       for %%f in (*.%%a) do @echo %dir%/%%f
    ))          

)
```

but this gives me the same output as `@echo /%%f`
what am i doing wrong?

Comment: another [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-in-batch-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028) issue.

Comment: How long is your list? If it's short, there might be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

First I don't understand why you insist to silent each command where you can simply silent all by a single `@echo off`

There is absolutely no need to change the current directory on each iteration, you can perform your task from where you are.

You can eliminate the trailing `\.` from the `FOR /R` variable by applying the `~f` modifier to `%%d` So with `%%~fd` the path `C:\test\.` becomes `C:\test`

```
@echo off
for /R %%d in (.) do for %%e in (%list%) do (
    for %%f in ("%%~fd\*.%%e") do echo %%f
)
```

Comment: well that might be helpfull but it doesn't really answer the question. How can i store %%d in a variable dir, so that i can use something like %dir:~3,-2%?

Comment: I missed that point, because the way you asked looked like you are just trying resolve the issue with trailing `\.` and even in your second attempted code, you didn't try to get any substring from `%dir%` like what you have showed in your above comment and without trying to do some manipulation to the variable using a variable doesn't make sense.So please update your question and code and show exactly what substring you want to get how you want to use it.

Comment: If your original intend for using a variable and getting substring from it was to resolve the issue with `\.` then this is a the correct answer I gave you there is no need to use a variable and your question becomes an instance of [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) which has been resolved but if you want to use a variable for something else or if your are just curious how can use variable in a code block then your question is duplicate which is already marked as such as I'm writing this comment.